# ggplot - plotting a second line of group mean values on top of figures of individual sites

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a short R function that plots individual figures for each site in a data frame. The data frame also contains a group identifier and I would like to plot a second line on each of the individual site figures for the "group means"

Here is some sample data:

```
tb <- tribble(
~x, ~y, ~group, ~site_name, ~site_id,
1, 1.2, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
2, 1.4, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
3, 1.6, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
4, 1.8, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
5, 2.0, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
6, 2.2, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
7, 1.9, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
8, 1.7, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
9, 1.5, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
10, 1.3, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
11, 1.1, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
12, 1.0, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
1, 1.1, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
2, 1.2, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
3, 1.3, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
4, 1.4, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
5, 1.5, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
6, 1.6, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
7, 2.7, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
8, 2.1, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
9, 2.1, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
10, 3.0, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
11, 1.1, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
12, 1.2, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
1, 2.2, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
2, 2.4, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
3, 2.6, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
4, 2.8, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
5, 3.0, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
6, 3.2, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
7, 2.9, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
8, 2.7, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
9, 2.5, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
10, 2.3, 'a', 'aa', 1, 
11, 2.1, 'a', 'ab', 2, 
12, 2.0, 'a', 'ac', 3, 
1, 2.1, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
2, 2.2, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
3, 2.3, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
4, 2.4, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
5, 2.5, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
6, 2.6, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
7, 3.7, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
8, 3.1, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
9, 3.1, 'b', 'bc', 6, 
10, 4.0, 'b', 'ba', 4, 
11, 3.1, 'b', 'bb', 5, 
12, 2.2, 'b', 'bc', 6
)
```

and here is my code for a function that creates a figure for each site:

```
# plot line for each site on it's own figure
site_figures <- function(df, na.rm = TURE, ...) {
site_list <- unique(df$site_id) 
site_name_list <- unique(df$site_name) 
  for (i in seq_along(site_list)) { 
    plot <- 
    ggplot(subset(df, df$site_id == site_list[i]), 
      aes(x, y)) +
    geom_line() + 
    ggtitle(paste(site_name_list[i], '\n', 
              sep = ''))
  print(plot) 
  }
} 
# call plotting function
site_figures(tb)
```

I am sure how to proceed. Ideally I'd like to layer another line, based on group means of the 'y', values on each site figure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your `group` column consists only of one group. So each "group mean" is the same line. But you can try to add s.th. like `stat_summary(aes(x, y, color=group), geom="line", fun.y="mean")`

Comment: I understand your point. The data I made up will not allow me to do what I need. I would need multiple "x" points for each site within each group (which is what my real data contains). As I think about this a little more, what I am trying to do is for each site figure, add and additional line which is the means for each "x" measure for each site within each group. For example... I have two groups "a" and "b". What I want to do, is make a figure for each site ("aa", "ab", "ac", "ba", "bb", and "bc") then for the each site plot  the site means by group on top. Sorry for earlier confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want, however there's no overlap in site ID between groups so you end up with some subplots that have only the group mean.  If instead you want site `aa` and `ba` to be in the same column, you should re-code your `site_name` variable before plotting.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

tb %>% group_by(group, x) %>% summarise(y=mean(y)) -> agg

tb %>% ggplot(mapping=aes(x=x, y=y)) +
    facet_grid(group ~ site_name) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_line(data=agg, colour='red')  # could use geom_smooth here instead
```

[image: plot by site, with overlaid group mean]

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
site_figures <- function(df, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {
  site_list <- unique(df$site_id) 
  site_name_list <- unique(df$site_name) 

  for (i in seq_along(site_list)) { 
    data_subset <- subset(df, df$site_id == site_list[i])
    plot <- 
      ggplot(data_subset, 
        aes(x, y)) +
      geom_line() + 
      geom_hline(yintercept = mean(data_subset$y)) + 
      ggtitle(paste(site_name_list[i], '\n', 
        sep = ''))
    print(plot) 
  }
} 
# call plotting function
site_figures(tb)
```

Comment: Instead of plotting a horizontal line based on the the y intercepts. How would you plot a geom_smooth line that represents all the data from each group (a and b). Those two lines would then be plotted on top of each site figure and site specific line? Is that more clear?